# ViewControllerType does not have a member named

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Please explain what's wrong with the code piece shown at screen attached. Thx in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring stored properties, you can't access other stored members of a class unless you're declaring a *lazy* property:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var controlDate = ...
    lazy var timeInterval: NSTimeInterval? = self.controlDate?.timeIntervalSinceNow

    // ...
}
```

However, that won't be executed until you try to look at the `timeInterval` property, which probably isn't what you want. I'd suggest declaring them as `nil`, then setting both of their values in the `viewDidLoad` method.